# Python lists if else concatenation adding elements

Tags: python, list, if-statement, concatenation

I'm trying to do this:

```
for i in range(len(daysDial)):
    if dayDial[i] in daysPresence:
        for j in range(len(daysPresence)):
            if daysDial[i]== daysPresence[j]:
                rowsPresence.append(dataPresencePy[j][1])

    else:
        rowsPresence.append("no presence")
```

in this other way:

```
rowsPresence = [dataPresencePy[j][1] for i in range(len(daysDial)) 
                if daysDial[i] in daysPresence else "no presence" 
                for j in range(len(daysPresence))
                if daysDial[i] == daysPresence[j]]
```

but it doesn't work properly. Is this possible to do.

Comment: Your indentation is all wonky - the `else` should line up with the `if`, probably. Make sure you don't mix tabs and spaces (use 4 spaces per indentation level). Be consistent. Also, "it doesn't works properly" is not a helpful problem description. Please improve your question.

Comment: Showing us code that doesn't do what you want it to and asking us to make it do what you want it to, without telling us what you want doesn't make sense.
 What are you trying to do and in what way does it not work?

Comment: Also, why on earth would you want to express a readable `for` loop with an incomprehensible list comprehension?

Comment: My question is if there any way to write the first code in the form in which it is written the second , ie , in a single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the loops in the wrong order; I think what you wanted is:

```
[[dataPresencePy[j][1] for j in range(len(daysPresence)) 
  if daysDial[i] == daysPresence[j]] 
 if daysDial[i] in daysPresence else "no presence" 
 for i in range(len(daysDial))]
```

But, as pointed out in the comments, this is much less readable and probably not much more performant than the unrolled loop version.

Also, it seems odd to have a list whose elements are either the string `"no presence"` or a list - why not `None`, or an empty list?

Comment: so, is better the first version than the second?, I thought it would be better to do it in one line.

Comment: @Madmartigan why did you think it would be better? Python values readability - the very fact that you struggled to write this suggests that it's not as clear what's happening. Unless this is a performance bottleneck, where the list comprehension can be slightly more efficient, I would use the original.

Comment: OK!, thanks a lot @jonrsharpe. I am new to pyhton , I'm starting. Thanks again.